# React JS Prevent onClick from Firing when Checkbox is checked

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, preventdefault, stoppropagation

I have a `Card` component with checkboxes.  When a user clicks on a card, another `Suggest` component opens.  However, when user clicks on checkbox, the `onClick` function runs also, still opening the `Suggestions` component. If there are no suggestions then it returns, and in that case the checkboxes work fine.  I tried using `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`, which I included `stopPropagation` the code below.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const onUpdateCB = (e,ischecked, loginuser, userid, setisChecked,handleCheck) => {
 e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(ischecked, loginuser, userid);

  fetch('http://localhost:3000/cb', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
      body:JSON.stringify({
      loginuser,
      userid,
      ischecked: ischecked
    })
  }).then(setisChecked(ischecked));
  return

};

const Card = props => {
  const [isChecked, setisChecked] = useState(props.ischecked);
  return (
    <div
      className="pointer bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 shadow-5"
      onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.id)}

    >
      <div>
        <h3>{props.name}</h3>
        <p>{props.company}</p>
        <p>{props.phone}</p>
        <p>{props.email}</p>
        <p>{props.city}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        My Network
        <input
          className="largeCheckbox"
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isChecked}
          onChange={(e) =>
            onUpdateCB(e,!isChecked, props.loginuser.id, props.id, setisChecked)
          }
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

HandleClick function

```
handleClick(id) {
    const updatedSuggest = suggest.map(sugg => {
      if (sugg.id === id) {
        this.setState({
          suggest: suggest.filter(suggest => suggest.id === id),
          route: "suggestions"
        });
        this.setState({ routed: true });
        this.setState({
          networkfilter: this.state.network.filter(netw => netw.id === id),
          route: "suggestions"
        });
        this.setState({ routed: true });
      }
      return;
    });
  }
```

Comment: See whether you can use ```event.target !== event.currentTarget``` check in the onClick function

Comment: Ganesh-Thx. Can you post how to add that?  Incidentally, I added the stopPropagation in the onClick, just like I had it in the onChange, and I was able to check the boxes, but then nothing happens when I click on the card....

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved this by changing the onChange to onClick and running stopPropagation:
  onClick={(event) =>
            onUpdateCB(!isChecked, props.loginuser.id, props.id, setisChecked,event.stopPropagation())
          }

Answer (score 0):

> event object consist target values and status. you can verify checked or not from event object `event.target.checked`
>
> Don't pass more than 4 arguments to a function. if you need more, then create object and pass

Comment: Where do i put this?

Comment: after event.stopPropagation() if user checked that checkbox it will return true otherwise false.

if(e.target.cheked){return; //function return if checkbox checked}

Answer (score 0):

You can check the target's DOM and compare if its what you're looking for. Checkout the following sandbox.

```
let checkboxDOM = document.getElementsByClassName('largeCheckbox');
if(e.target !== checkboxDOM[0])
{
  //TODO Your function here for Card click
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-easley-mmn2o

NOTE : Not the best way to do it perhaps ( lookout for other's solutions ) . I opted @Ganesh Rathinavel's approach to make it work. Credits to him if it works.

Comment: I couldn't make it work using this.  When i check the box it still opens the other component and doesn't check doesn't appear. 
 handleClick=(id,event) => {
  let checkboxDOM = document.getElementsByClassName('largeCheckbox');
if(event.target !== checkboxDOM[0]) { //Code for Click

Comment: I finally solved by changing the onChange to onClick and running stopPropagation().  
 onClick={(event) =>
            onUpdateCB(!isChecked, props.loginuser.id, props.id, setisChecked,event.stopPropagation())
          }

Comment: Glad you found an answer

Answer (score 0):

My WorkAround was stop handling the onChange in input checkbox, just by handling the outer div was working for me...

```
<div
      className="pointer bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 shadow-5"
          onClick={(e) =>
            onUpdateCB(e,!isChecked, props.loginuser.id, props.id, setisChecked)
          }
    >
      <div>
        <h3>{props.name}</h3>
        <p>{props.company}</p>
        <p>{props.phone}</p>
        <p>{props.email}</p>
        <p>{props.city}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        My Network
        <input
          className="largeCheckbox"
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isChecked}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
```